# Is it possible to hide directories on share using Apple ACL?

Tags: macos, acl, osx-server

I'm just setting an office server running Maverick Server.

I can setup control to directories and block some users or group from accessing certain things.

However, I can't seem to find any way to *hide* directories that are not accessible to particular users or groups.

The directories appear with the red forbidden/no entry sign but I would like to hide them entirely from users who do not have access to them.

Is there a way to do this?

The current setup make posix minimal (rwx------) so that they wont interfere with ACLs..

then there's a main group that has access to most things everywhere except a couple of folders (RW inherited everywhere, then removed on a couple of sub folders)

then there's a separate group that has access to a couple of directories (read on top share, then read/write on a couple of subdirectories)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find a way. And I searched a long way through the internet.

As far as I understood the whole thing it is like this: The entries inside a folder are like entries in a text-file with the "folder" being that file. If you are entitled to read that textfile (the folder) you can read **all** of the text. Thats the 'read'-attribute of a folder. So at displaying the content of a folder the Mac shows you the file content (everything) Then it goes through the single folders and tries to show the Icon of the folder and recognizes, that there is no way of reading the content of that certain folder, so it displays the one-way sign.

Sounds a bit strange, makes somehow sense when you get the idea, and is still somewhat user-unfriendly.

You *can* do that using other filesystems like NTFS (which is not officially supported on a mac). Not sure whether AndrewFilesystem can do that, but that's like taking a sledgehammer to crack a nut....

If you find a way do call back as I'd be **very** interested!!!

Comment: Thanks for your input, good to hear someone else's experience with it.